# Interpretation of a sampled signal in the frequency domain

Tags: frequency-spectrum, sampling, frequency-domain

Suppose we have a signal $y(t)$. For sampling we use a Dirac $\delta$ function.
The sampled function is $\widetilde{y}(t)$.
So $$\widetilde{y}(t) = y(t)\cdot\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT).$$ The Fourier transformation is $$\widetilde{Y}(\omega)=\mathcal{F\{\widetilde{y}(t)\}} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}y(nT)e^{-i2\pi\omega nT}$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $\omega$ angular frequency. $y(nT)$ are the sampled points but I am having problems in understanding what $e^{-i2\pi\omega nT}$ of $\widetilde{Y}(\omega)$ means? I could write it down with $\cos$ and $\sin$ but this does not make it clearer. I would appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: It's a complex sinusoid. I guess you have a textbook that introduces the Fourier transform – read that; this term is so fundamental that I'm almost 100% certain it's covered in there.

Answer (score 1):

First, $i$ is not the imaginary part, but the imaginary unit. This tells you that the signal, under suitable conditions, admits a [discrete time Fourier transform](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Discrete_Time_Fourier_Transform.html).  Its is a linear representation of the discrete signal. It provides you with a spectral interpretation, ie a view of the content of the signal  as a linear combination of waves, pure frequencies  indexed by a continuous index $\omega$. Pure frequencies are cisoids or [complex exponentials/sinusoids](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Complex_Sinusoids.html), by definition

$$e^{-i2\pi\omega nT} = \cos(-2\pi\omega nT)+i\sin(-2\pi\omega nT)\,.$$

The relative importance (weight) and "timing" of these waves is given by $\tilde{Y}(\omega)$, by its magnitude and phase, respectively. Another interpretation of the sum of products is a scalar product between the signal and the different waves. If the scalar product is high, the signal looks like the pure wave  a lot, and the corresponding frequency is very "present" in the signal. If is is low, this component is not really present in the signal. The whole spectrum, made of all the $\tilde{Y}(\omega)$, tells you about the content in "each" frequency in your data.

The two links above drive you to the excellent site of J. O. Smith, and [the mathematics of the discrete Fourier transform](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mdft/), an perfect starting point to understand these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The given expression for the Fourier transform of the sampled signal $y(t)$ is useful in the sense that it shows that the spectrum of the sampled signal equals the discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) of the discrete-time signal

$$y_d[n]=y(nT)$$

$$Y_d(\omega)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}y_d[n]e^{-jn\omega}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}y(nT)e^{-j\Omega nT}=\widetilde{Y}(\Omega)\tag{1}$$

where $\omega$ is defined as $\omega=\Omega T$, with the angular frequency $\Omega$ of the continuous-time signal, and the sampling interval $T$. Equation $(1)$ shows that $Y_d(\omega)=\widetilde{Y}(\Omega)$ is a periodic function with Fourier series coefficients $y(nT)$.

However, the expression $(1)$ does not give much insight into the relation between $\widetilde{Y}(\Omega)$ (or $Y_d(\omega)$) and the spectrum $Y(\Omega)$ of the original continuous-time signal $y(t)$. (And that's the way I interpret your question). This relation becomes explicit when you derive $\widetilde{Y}(\Omega)$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}\widetilde{Y}(\Omega)&=\mathcal{F}\left\{y(t)\cdot\sum_n\delta(t-nT)\right\}\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathcal{F}\{y(t)\}\star\mathcal{F}\left\{\sum_n\delta(t-nT)\right\}\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}Y(\Omega)\star\frac{2\pi}{T}\sum_n\delta\left(\Omega-\frac{2\pi n}{T}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{T}\sum_nY\left(\Omega-\frac{2\pi n}{T}\right)\tag{2}\end{align}$$

where $\star$ denotes convolution. Note that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent, even if that's not immediately obvious. The expression $(2)$ very clearly shows that sampling results in periodization of the spectrum, and this will result in aliasing if the spectrum $Y(\Omega)$ is not properly band-limited.